# Insert into select statement that sets all other columns to null

Tags: sql, select, insert, db2, dashdb

I am trying to run this insert into select statement:

```
insert into xyz (select t1.column1, t1.column2 from table1 t1, table2 t2 
where t1.column1 = t2.column1)
```

But get the error: "The number of values assigned is not the same as the number of specified or implied columns or variables"

I want to set all other columns to null (e.g. t1.column3 through t1.column50).

Is there a way to do this without having to explicitly list all the columns out in the select statement?

```
insert into xyz (select  t1.column1, t1.column2, null as column3, null as column4, null as 
column5... from table1 t1, table2 t2 
where t1.column1 = t2.column1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list the columns in the insert list. E.g.

```
insert into xyz ( column1, column2 )
select t1.column1, t1.column2
from table1 t1
,    table2 t2 
where t1.column1 = t2.column1
```

so, for example

```
create table xyz( column1 int not null, column2 int not null, column3 int);
create table table1( column1 int not null, column2 int not null);
create table table2( column1 int not null);
insert into table1 values (1,2),(2,3);
insert into table2 values (1),(2);
select * from xyz;
```

gives

```
 COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN3
 ------- ------- -------
       1       2    NULL
       2       3    NULL
```